# What is the difference between using double arrow and single colon when define an array in PHP

Tags: php

I usually use

```
 $header = array(
    'Content-type: application/json',
    'x-app-key: 123'
 );
```

to define an array, and sometimes I use

```
$header = array(
    'Content-type' => 'application/json',
    'x-app-key' => '123'
);
```

Sometimes one works and the other one does not.

Could I ask what is the difference with these two ways to define an array in PHP? Thank you.

Comment: They are not equal. The first is an array of strings with number indexes, the second is key->value pairs.

Comment: Try using `print_r()` and you should see how the arrays are held.

Comment: As for the title - the single colon in the first array is just part of the value, it has nothing to do with defining an array.

Comment: @aynber Thank you for explaining! So to define an HTTP request header, I should always use the first way right?

Comment: @JamesChen No, it completely depends on the rest of your code and what your goal is. Either will work depending on how you loop through and print the headers out, although the second way would allow for better code. You probably need to learn some basics about how arrays work in PHP.

Comment: If you're using cURL and the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` option, you want to use the first code.

Comment: @ChrisWhite ok thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's completely different. when you use

```
 $header = array(
    'Content-type: application/json',
    'x-app-key: 123'
 );
```

you're just defining an array of strings. the array would be

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> string(30) "Content-type: application/json" 
    [1]=> string(14) "x-app-key: 123" 
}
```

but if you use

```
$header = array(
    'Content-type' => 'application/json',
    'x-app-key' => '123'
);
```

you will create an associative array, like so

```
array(2) { 
     ["Content-type"]=> string(16) "application/json" 
     ["x-app-key"]=> string(3) "123" 
}
```

please refer to [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) documentation for a complete explanation

hope it helps!